# SIGABRT in c++ code on IOS

Tags: android, c++, ios

Good day!
I have a c++ library and C-wrapper, so it can be compiled and used in android and ios os.

When I ran my code on linux and android it works fine, but on ios i have SIGABRT.

the functions are :

```
int getBytesFromBinary(char *ptr, size_t size, char * const out) {
    std::string binary(ptr, size);
     std::string ret_string =  NAMESPACE::getStringFromBinary(binary);
   //checkings and return
}

std::string getStringFromBinary(const std::string &binary) {
    std::string out_str = "";
    MyObject object;
    //parce binary to object
    ....
    //
    out_str.append(std::string((const char*)object.data.ptr, object.data.len));

    return out_str;
}
```

Error :

```
   malloc: *** error for object 0x1001260cc: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

But error goes away if we change

```
out_str.append(...) 
return out_str;
```

to simply

```
return std::string((const char*)object.data.ptr, object.data.len);
```

Why that happens?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the code in `//parse binary to object`.  I think you are overwriting some memory somewhere, and ios is managing to catch it.

Comment: The problem is probably in MyObject and you have not shown us that code.

Comment: in //parse binary to object there is another library - not mine. As I said - no problem on linux and android. Different compiler? Arch issuer?

Comment: There's a bug in your code, somewhere, that results in undefined behavior and memory corruption. Just because a C++ program crashes a particular point does not mean that's where the bug is. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, or running off past the end of the array, or countless of other typical types of undefined behavior can occur anywhere, and execution could continue well past that point, with the code eventually crashing when it attempts to use the corrupted memory. Welcome to C++.